# How to hyperlink templates specific file on index.html in Zola

Tags: html, zola

I am trying to hyperlink gallery.html located in the templates folder at the index.html at Zola.

Structure of the project

```
content
templates
  - gallery.html
  - index.html
  - base.html
static
config.toml
```

I tried to use `link_to` it didn't work to link.

```
<a href="{{ link_to("gallery.html") }}">Gallery</a>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zola does not have a `link_to()` function. To add a hyperlink to the gallery you need to target gallery’s template output file (in the `content` directory) and not the template.

index.html:

```html
<a href="{{ get_url(path="@/pages/gallery.md") }}">Gallery</a>
```

See Zola’s [internal linking](https://www.getzola.org/documentation/content/linking/#internal-links).